# Laravel error ; Controller method not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have in routes.php :

```
Route::any('project/(:num)', array('as' =>'pr', 'uses'=>'ProjectController@getIndex'));
Route::any('project/(:num)/(:any)', array('as' =>'pr', 'uses'=>'ProjectController@(:2)'));
```

and I am getting an error : Controller method not found

What is the problem I have getIndex

Thanks

Comment: What route do you exactly access while getting this error?

Comment: /project/2 and I get this error while I access this page

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what you expect this should call? `'uses'=>'ProjectController@(:2)'`

Comment: to be honest with you I don't know what this suppose to be doing its a Laravel 3 and I am moving the project to Laravel 4

Comment: Since you're already migrating the project, you may want to consider moving to Laravel 5, instead. It was just released last week.